# Query List Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries

```
var ProductItemsDictionary = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
```

Is it possible to use linq to search the list and find a dictionary based on a key inside that dictionary and retrieve the value?

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is, but is it worth? See for instance the **dotctor**'s answer. It will do the job, but is inefficient - 2 key lookups (one for checking and one for retrieving the value), compiler generated class and heap allocation (because of the `specificKey` variable capture), etc. Less code? More readable? What about the non linq equivalent:

```
static void Foo(List<Dictionary<string, string>> ProductItemsDictionary, string key)
{
    string value;
    foreach (var dictionary in ProductItemsDictionary)
        if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value)) { /* Use value */ }
    // Not found
}
```

Zero allocations, minimum key lookups, good readability (IMO) - what else do we need? :-)